# I need a basic guide to using Hamachi

Tags: hamachi

I have installed Hamachi on my Windows 7 PC and created a network.

What next? I can see an IP address in the Hamachi Window 5.x.x.x: I tried accessing this ip address on a laptop connected to my home wi-fi. No luck.

I am confused...The official user guide is confusing. All I want is to access my files on the Windows 7 PC.

Comment: You might consider reviewing the questions you've asked in the past and choosing an answer if there was one that provided a solution to your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you cannot connect to this IP is because you will need to install hamachi on that other computer as well.

Once you do this, you will need to create a network on one of the computers. On the other computer join an existing network with the name and password you created. As long as both computers are turned on, have internet connection and hamachi is running, they will be able to access each other.

Update:

One of the nicest features that I have not found elsewhere is that you're able to create one of three different types of networks with Hamachi.

[image]

MESH: I use this for my home computers. I do not need to restrict access to these machines and hide them from other members of my Home Network.

HUB & Spoke: I use this for my Minecraft server. I will allow friends to connect to this machine (which happens to be part of a virtual cloud) and play on our Minecraft server. I absolutely do not want them to be able to access other computers on my network nor do I want them to access each others. Even if 15 people are connected here, they would only see the Minecraft server.

GATEWAY: This is awesome if you need to travel and need access to your network at work or something. In a small office, you can use this as a secure entry point to different things on your network while away. This would be similar to installing Hamachi on each computer at the office without the pain of doing so. Not used often for day to day home needs.

Comment: ok I understand...So I cannot simply access my Windows PC from anywhere in the world or any PC

Comment: correct. You will need hamachi installed on each computer that you're trying to access your "server". The IP address "5.x.x.x" is a Virtual IP that doesn't really exist to anyone except for computers within the network you create.

Comment: What about web access via my Logmein Account? Can i access my files via the website? I can see the network attached to my account

Comment: As of right now there is not a way to do that. You will need to set up hamachi on the computer.

Comment: If you explain what you're trying to accomplish, there may be other solutions better than hamachi. If you just need a 'secure' place to store files and access anywhere without software then Hamachi might not be the best for you. You can look into www.dropbox.com which would allow you to store 2GB (initially) of data for free. Refer other friends and family to DropBox and you can expand your size.

Comment: Nice point with DropBox is that you can just install their program on your computer at home and it will create a folder. Anything inside that folder will automatically be uploaded to the Drop box cloud. You can then go to their website and access your files.

Comment: Its OK, I use both Sugarsync and Dropbox so I am familiar with that tech. I guess what I was looking for was to access my home files from anywhere in the world and from any PC and without any Cloud storage.

Comment: You may want to look into LogMeIn Free. This will allow you to RDP into your machine. It's a free service as well. 

Hamachi sounds like it will do what you want, but you would need the client on both machines.

Have you thought about an FTP server? I dunno if your home ISP will allow that kind of traffic though.

Comment: Yes LogmeIn is my best solution at the moment. Thanks